# Correct len() 32-bit unicode strings in Python

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I am facing a problem with 32-bit unicode strings in Python 2.7. A simple declaration such as:

```
s = u'\U0001f601'
print s
```

Will print a nice  (smiley face) in the shell (if the shell supports unicode). The problem is that when I try:

```
print len(s), s.encode('latin-1', errors='replace')
```

I get different responses for different platforms. In Linux, I get:

```
1 ?
```

But in Mac, I get:

```
2 ??
```

Is the string declaration correct? Is this a bug in Python for Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS X Python has been compiled with [UCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set)-2 (really UTF-16) support versus UCS-4 support for Linux. This means that a [**surrogate pair**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) with a length of 2 characters is being used to represent the [SMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) character on OS X.

Comment: Nevertheless, as I'm not dealing with encoded strings (`str`), whether it uses a pair of characters or just one should be irrelevant. I mean, in the end isn't that just a single unicode character? Can this be considered a bug or a platform incompatibility?

Comment: It is a single Unicode character, but it is encoded internally regardless. And then decoded incorrectly, which is the bug.